# Passing the being looped element to event handler

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

How do I pass the element that is being loop to event handler.

**foo.hbs**

```
<div>
    {{#each products}}
        // some html code
        <p>{{this}}</p>                            <!-- output product object -->
        <button onclick="foo(this)">Add</button>   <!-- output button object-->
        <button onclick="foo({{this._id}})">Add</button>   <!-- uncaught syntax error -->

    {{/each}}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function foo(product) {
        console.log(product);
    }
</script>
```

The above code: `product` argument gives me the `HTMLButton` instead of `product` of current iteration.

---

**Question:** How do I pass `product` instead of `button` element to the handler?
I'm using `express-handlerbars`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
this.parentNode
```

which refers to html parent.

and in your function:

console.log(product.id);

console.log(typeof(product)); //display object

Console print html, but product is object you sent from onclick. So you can access to any related properties.

Hope it can help.

Comment: The result is <div>, how do I get product?

Comment: Have you html version officielle code ? Your production must have an id, cet id.

Comment: There is an id. Once I can access product, I can access any property of product. The problem is I don't know how to get the product object.

Comment: I tried `{{this._id}}`, it yields `product._id` in DOM inspection. However, I got `uncaught syntax error`.